# A pair of function for componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to call a pair of function for componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount. 
Like adding event listener and removing it.

Currently I'm writing these in componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount separately. but it's error prone because it might be forgotten to write one of these.

Can it be written as a pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `React.createClass` syntax you can create a mixin. [Read more about mixins in the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins). Here is a simple example for listening to window resize event:

```
var WindowResizeListenerMixin = {
  doSomething: function() {
    ...
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.doSomething, false);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.doSomething, false);
  }
};
```

Then use it in a React component like:

```
var ComponentWithWindowResizeListener = React.createClass({
  mixins: [WindowResizeListener],
  ...
});
```

So you can reuse this mixin whenever you want to do the same in the `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle events with other components.

Although mixins aren't deprecated yet it seems the React team is moving in the direction of removing them eventually since [they aren't supported with ES6 syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-mixins). However, a nice pattern I've found to achieve the same functionality of mixins is to create [higher-order components](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775), or functions that take a component as an argument and returns that component wrapped with a parent component. If you add lifecycle events to this parent component you can reuse it the same way. So with the same example with listening to window resize event:

```
function WindowResizeEnhance(DecoratedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    doSomething() {
      ...
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.doSomething, false);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.doSomething, false);
    }

    render() {
      return <DecoratedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
}
```

And to use it with a React component:

```
class ComponentWithWindowResizeListener extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export default WindowResizeEnhance(ComponentWithWindowResizeListener);
```

Comment: I'm trying mixin. Can I pass component's method to mixin as a callback?

Comment: I also read https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750 and understood higher-order components are way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
var TimerExample = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){

        // This is called before our render function. The object that is 
        // returned is assigned to this.state, so we can use it later.

        return { elapsed: 0 };
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){

        // componentDidMount is called by react when the component 
        // has been rendered on the page. We can set the interval here:

        this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 50);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function(){

        // This method is called immediately before the component is removed
        // from the page and destroyed. We can clear the interval here:
        debugger;   
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    },

    tick: function(){

        // This function is called every 50 ms. It updates the 
        // elapsed counter. Calling setState causes the component to be re-rendered

        this.setState({elapsed: new Date() - this.props.start});
    },

    render: function() {

        var elapsed = Math.round(this.state.elapsed / 100);

        // This will give a number with one digit after the decimal dot (xx.x):
        var seconds = (elapsed / 10).toFixed(1);    

        // Although we return an entire <p> element, react will smartly update
        // only the changed parts, which contain the seconds variable.

        return <p>This example was started <b>{seconds} seconds</b> ago.</p>;
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <TimerExample start={Date.now()} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```